# What language are web apps written in?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I've taught myself HTML and CSS and I'm in the process of going into Javascript. I see a lot of things written about web apps (guessing they are the type of thing you get on the Chrome store etc.) but I can't find a definitive guide as to what language they are written in. I know extensions are written in javascript, but what about web apps?

Comment: Web apps are application in the form of web pages. They are written using PHP, ASP.NET and other server side scripting, just like websites.

Comment: I think that softwares from Chrome store are extensions/add-ons for browser, they are not web apps.

Comment: @dpp: The web store consists of apps as well.

Comment: @pimvdb You mean the web store is a web app or web store sells web apps? I'm kinda confuse.

Comment: @dpp: Well, both I think :) The web store contains extensions/app/themes.

Answer (score 4):

A web application is any application that uses a web browser as a client. The application can be as simple as a message board or a guest sign-in book on a website, or as complex as a word processor or a spreadsheet.

The 'client' is used in client-server environment to refer to the program the person uses to run the application. A client-server environment is one in which multiple computers share information such as entering information into a database. ***The 'client' is the application used to enter the information, and the 'server' is the application used to store the information,***

Web applications commonly use a combination of server-side script (ASP, PHP, etc) and client-side script (HTML, Javascript, etc.) to develop the application.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side web apps can be written in any language which can output text. All that's required is that there is some way for a web server (as in the server software, e.g. Apache) to run the script so that it can send the output to the requesting browser. If that output is valid HTML then brilliant, a web page can be rendered

Comment: I have a question, you said "server-side web apps". Does it mean, there are client-side web apps too?

Comment: Web apps have a client side component and a server side component.

Comment: @Quentin You mean client-scripts and markups?

Comment: Every web app has a server-side component, otherwise it would just be an "app". It also has a client-side component, which could be HTML/CSS(/Javascript) when running in a browser, or even a native desktop executable. I only made the distinction because the OP mentioned the Chrome store, which contains a lot of extensions, which are client-side apps (or, possible the client-side portion of another web app)

Comment: The "server-side web apps" confused me. AFAIK, no web app is without client-side component. So I thought that "server-side web apps" do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Web app consists of a server and a client side. Server side can be written in a any programming language. It would be convenient if the language and the libraries support web development. On the client side the norm is web standards like JavaScript, html and css.

Answer (score 0):

A web app is an app coded in any or many of the laguanges of the web, i.e. html, css, javascript, php, asp.net etc. Web apps can be run in a regular browser, in a mobile browser or can be wrapped as apps to be downloaded from Android Market, AppStore etc.